# Authorize a session for any user with the iOS Social Framework?

Tags: ios, facebook, twitter

Is it possible to authenticate a user to post to any Twitter or Facebook account from their iOS app? By this I mean not an account thats set it your Settings App. I'm hoping it can be done with their new iOS Social Framework as I know the Twitter and Facebook APIs will not always be supported.

I want to be able to enter the credentials of any user and make a post as them.

Comment: I might be misinterpreting the question. The social framework will allow posting with any twitter or facebook accounts that are authorized through the settings menu on a particular device. It will always be from the client's account, not something you set.

Comment: Are you sure you understand how Twitter works? A user's Twitter feed is simply the collection of all posts made by users they follow; you cannot post to a specific user's feed.

Comment: So I want to post as any user provided I can authorize it.

Comment: I've updated my question. Hopefully it is more clear.

Answer (score 2):

Your questions is kind of unclear, but it comes down to this: As an app developer, you are only allowed the permissions to the social account that the user is logged into inside of the settings app (and only after the user grants the app permission).

For the iOS social framework, the user is allowed to be simultaneously logged into multiple Twitter accounts, except only one Facebook account.

Read up on the Social.framework here: [Social.framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Social/Reference/Social_Framework/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012233)

And the facebook open graph api here: [Facebook Open Graph](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/)